# How to add new service to kafka pipeline without downtime?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, continuous-deployment

To give more context, we have kafka streams applications in JAVA
lets say, currently the pipeline looks like
**current State**: `PRODUCER -[topic1]> CONSUMER`

now, I want to introduce a new service between producer and consumer lets call it INTERMEDIATE
the new pipeline would look like

**new State**: `PRODUCER -[topic1]> INTERMEDIATE -[topic2]> CONSUMER`

**What we do now**
shutdown PRODUCER, let CONSUMER read all the messages in topic1, then deploy INTERMEDIATE, update source topic in CONSUMER, then restart PRODUCER again, but this causes downtime, taking around 10 minutes.

**Another way we tried is**
Use a date field in the message. Launch INTERMEDIATE and let it write to topic2, and in CONSUMER if date is `< today` read from `topic1` else read from `topic2`,  wait for sometime and the all the messages are read form `topic2`. But here we need to write some throw away code. and some other issues as well

--

Is there any standard tool, script or process that people follow to achive this with no/minimal downtime and with no throw away code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html